# Trying to make a function in C that copies one string onto another

Tags: c, string, function

I have to make a function that accepts two string pointers as arguments - one having content, and one being empty, and that copies the content of the first one onto the second one.

How would I go about doing this? Here is the code I have, but it just crashes when run:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void strcopy1(char* mainStr[], char* emptyStr[], int size)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       *emptyStr[i] = *mainStr[i];   //The issue is on this line. How do I do this?
   }
}

int main(void)
{
    char *s1 = "Barrel";
    char *e1;
    printf("mainStr is: %s\n", s1);
    printf("emptyStr is: %s\n", e1);
    strcopy1(&s1, &e1, 7);
    printf("mainStr is: %s\n", s1);
    printf("emptyStr is: %s\n", e1);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't allocated any memory for `e1` to point to.

Comment: You shouldn't be passing `&s1` and `&e1`, just pass `s1` and `e1`.

Comment: 1) `*emptyStr[i] = *mainStr[i];` --> `emptyStr[i] = mainStr[i];` 2) Delete `printf("emptyStr is: %s\n", e1);` (`e1` is uninitilezed variable, not empty.) 3) `strcopy1(&s1, &e1, 7);` --> `strcopy1(&s1, &e1, 1);`

Comment: After changing the e1 line to be "char *e1[7];" or "char e1 = "      "; and removing the ampersands, it still crashes.

Comment: You need to pay attention to the compiler warnings. You should have gotten a bunch of warnings because of your mistakes.

Comment: Thanks BLUEPIXY - but why does using 1 as the size work?

Comment: `char *s1;` is equivalent to `char *s1[1];`.

Answer (score 3):

Several problems:

1. You didn't allocate space for the destination string.
2. You don't need to pass pointers to the variables, just pass the pointer variables themselves.
3. You can't print the empty string before calling the function, since you haven't initialized any of its contents.
4. The elements of the arrays are `char`, not pointer to `char`, so you don't need to use `*mainStr[i]` or `*emptyStr[i]`.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void strcopy1(char mainStr[], char emptyStr[], int size)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       emptyStr[i] = mainStr[i];
   }
}

int main(void)
{
    char *s1 = "Barrel";
    size_t len = strlen(s1) + 1; // Add 1 for the trailing null byte
    char *e1 = malloc(len);
    printf("mainStr is: %s\n", s1);
    strcopy1(s1, e1, len);
    printf("mainStr is: %s\n", s1);
    printf("emptyStr is: %s\n", e1);
    free(e1); // Always free dynamically-allocated memory
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the line where you are calling the function. I found a solution for you that works fine.

```
copy_string(char *target, char *source)
{
    while(*source)
    {
        *target = *source;        
        source++;        
        target++;
    }    
    *target = '\0';
}
```

This function will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

The following is your code with corrections annotated in-line:

```
// pointer to pointer is not needed, change argument to char *
//void strcopy1(char* mainStr[], char* emptyStr[], int size)
void strcopy1(char* mainStr, char* emptyStr, int size)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       //*emptyStr[i] = *mainStr[i];   //The issue is on this line. How do I do this?
       emptyStr[i] = mainStr[i]; //reference variable, not pointer to variable
   }
}

int main(void)
{
    char *s1 = "Barrel";
    char *e1 = {0};  // initialize variable
    e1 = malloc(strlen(s1)+1); //allocate memory to target string (+1 for NULL)
    if(e1)//ensure e1 memory was created
    {
       printf("mainStr is: %s\n", s1);
       printf("emptyStr is: %s\n", e1);
       strcopy1(s1, e1, 7); //string variables are already pointers
                         //no need for the "address of" operator
       printf("mainStr is: %s\n", s1);
       printf("emptyStr is: %s\n", e1);
       free(e1); //always free memory when explicitly created using malloc()
    }   

    return 0;//add return to match your 'main' prototype
}
```

In answer to your question in comments:
*After changing the e1 line to be "char *e1[7];" or "char e1 = " "; and removing the ampersands, it still crashes.*

1)  Changing `char *e1` to `char *e1[7]` is creating `char *[7]`, but you need either a `char *` or a `char [7]` for the job.  Either will create containers adequate for use as a C string passed as an argument.  (however `char *` needs memory allocated (`[m][c]alloc`) before use)

2) Regarding removing ampersands, this was explained above as well, but basically, the `&` is the address of operator, since C string *names* (variables) are already pointing to the address of the string, the `&` operator is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

First you're trying to display a non initialized String which is impossible. 
Second, I don't understand why the parameters are an array of pointers. 
Here's what I propose :

```
void strcopy1(char *mainStr, char *emptyStr) {
   while (*mainStr) {
      *emptyStr = *mainStr;
       mainStr++;
       emptyStr++;
    }
  *emptyStr = '\0';
 }

int main(void)
{
   char *s1 = "Barrel";
   char *e1;
   printf("mainStr is: %s\n", s1);
   strcopy1(&s1, &e1);
   printf("mainStr is: %s\n", s1);
   printf("emptyStr is: %s\n", e1);
}
```